# What does "minds her helium like a lady" mean in "The Terrible Voyage of the Toad"?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, edward-page-mitchell

I have the following passage from '[The Terrible Voyage of the Toad](http://www.gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0606901h.html#s15)' (1878) by Edward Page Mitchell:

> "Without intendin' to disperidge," continued the deacon, "her bottom's more putty'n timber."
>
> "Putty or no putty," rejoined the owner of the Toad, "she sails afore the wind like a thing of life and minds her helium like a lady."

I don’t understand what he means by “she sails afore the wind like a thing of life and minds her helium like a lady”, can someone kindly explain this to me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TL;DR: ‘Helium’ is a misprint for ‘**hellum**’ which is a dialect spelling of ‘**helm**’.

Let’s get the easier parts out of the way before we tackle ‘helium’. The *Toad* is a “sloop, of 8,825–10,000 registered tonnage”. I don’t really understand this description—a ‘[sloop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloop)’ is normally a sailing vessel with a single fore-and-aft rigged mast, but a vessel of 10,000 [gross register tonnage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_register_tonnage) would be far too large for a single mast—a five-masted [clipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper) might not be so large. Let’s be generous and assume that this discrepancy is a plain hint that the tale is a tall one.

In a sailing vessel, to “sail afore [before] the wind” means to travel downwind, that is, in the same, or similar, direction as the wind. To do so “like a thing of life” means that in this [point of sail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_sail) it responds quickly to the wind and waves, pitching, rolling and yawing like a living thing.

The word ‘helium’ is a misprint (probably arising from an optical character recognition error) for ‘hellum’, as you can see in the Google Books snippet view for the 1973 Doubleday edition of Mitchell’s collection *The Crystal Man*:

[image]

The spelling ‘hellum’ indicates a dialect pronunciation of ‘helm’, meaning the steering gear of the ship, presumably a [ship’s wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship%27s_wheel) in the case of the *Toad*. There are lots of other dialect spellings in this passage, for example ‘thurowly’ for ‘thoroughly’ and ‘disperidge’ for ‘disparage’. For a ship to ‘mind her helm’ means to be obedient to steering, so that when the steersman turns the wheel the ship turns quickly and without resistance: ‘like a lady’ means ‘gracefully’.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I was so confused. You cleared my doubts. Thank you again.